# id in controls automatically changes

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery

I'm writing a bit of jquery to access a dropdown, but .net automatically changes the id by adding ctl00$...

Is there any way to stop it from changing it?

Thanks

Comment: Is it an option for you to not use Id but use classes instead to pick up your dropdown? You can have more than one class assigned to the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID is changed because your page could have multiple controls containing child items with duplicate IDs, or the master page might as well.  I find it best to only use class selectors when dealing with jQuery and ASP.NET WebForms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on ASP.NET 4.0 you could use [static or predictable ids](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/727644.aspx). If not you could append a CSS class to your control and use [CSS class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) in jQuery instead of id selector.